# Ranger Custom Command to Move File to Pre-Specified Directory?

Tags: bash, shell

Using ranger,

1. How can create a `:command` which moves the currently selected files to a prespecified directory? Say, by selecting a `file` and typing `:move_to_path` it runs

   mv file /path/location/file
2. How could I do the same as with (1) but instead bind a key `:command`? Say by highlighting a file and typing `mf` it runs `:move_to_path` on the selected file.

## Edit

The question is about this ranger: https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a ranger user, but I saw an entry in the ranger wiki that seems to be helpful : https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Commands.

TL;DR : edit the file `~/.config/ranger/commands.py`

```
from ranger.api.commands import Command
class move_to_path(Command):
    """
    :move_to_path
    Move file to a directory
    """
    def execute(self):
        import shutil # for shutil.copy, os.rename works fine too
        shutil.move(self.fm.thisfile.path, "/your/directory/" + self.fm.thisfile.basename)
```

You now have your command that you can launch with `:move_to_path`. You could write python code to know where to get the directory name : fixed, in a configuration file of your choice, etc.

Now, to add a keybinding, let's have a look at : https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Keybindings or at : http://ranger.nongnu.org/ranger.1.html#KEY-BINDINGS
If I'm not wrong, you can edit the `~/.config/ranger/config/rc.conf` and add a keybinding here.
For instance, you can add a line :

```
map mf move_to_path
```

I think this should do the trick.
And thank you for making me discover ranger, I'll try it tomorrow :)

Edit :
To move multiple selected files, you could do :

```
    def execute(self):
        import shutil # for shutil.copy, os.rename works fine too
        from os import basename
        for file in self.fm.thistab.get_selection():
            shutil.move(file, "/your/directory/" + basename(file))
```

Comment: This works PERFECTLY, except it's not `~/.config/ranger/config/rc.conf` it's actually `~/.config/ranger/rc.conf` that needs to be edited with the `map mf move_to_path`.

Comment: Also: do you know if there's an easy way to make this command affect selected files as opposed to the currently viewed file?

Comment: I'll have to try to make an acceptable answer, but I think the wiki on github contains a lot of information, it is also possible to see the python source files to get some hints.
I'll edit the answer.